# Text Processing: Offset a date value in a column based on another column value

Tags: awk

I have text file with date value in YYYYMMDD format in column 4, and a month offset in column 5.

```
a1|b1|c1|20190101|1|1|11|A|D
a1|b1|c1|20190101|2|2|12|B|E
a1|b1|c1|20190101|3|3|13|C|F
a2|b2|c2|20190101|1|4|14|G|J
a2|b2|c2|20190101|2|5|15|H|K
a2|b2|c2|20190101|3|6|16|I|L
```

I would like to replace the value in column 5 with the logic of 
date -d '(value in column 4) -(value in column 5) months +1 months'  +'%Y%m%d'

So end result should look like the following

```
a1|b1|c1|20190101|20190101|1|11|A|D
a1|b1|c1|20190101|20181201|2|12|B|E
a1|b1|c1|20190101|20181101|3|13|C|F
a2|b2|c2|20190101|20190101|4|14|G|J
a2|b2|c2|20190101|20181201|5|15|H|K
a2|b2|c2|20190101|20181101|6|16|I|L
```

I tied using awk -f offsetMonths.awk

```
BEGIN{
    FS="|"
    OFS = FS
}
{
#   Date field is in column 4, offset is in column 5
#   Replace column 5 with the offset date
    "date -d '"$4" -"$5" months +1 months'  +'%Y%m%d' " | getline l
    $5 = l
    print $0
}
```

What I am getting is

```
a1|b1|c1|20190101|20190101|1|11|A|D
a1|b1|c1|20190101|20181201|2|12|B|E
a1|b1|c1|20190101|20181101|3|13|C|F
a2|b2|c2|20190101|20181101|4|14|G|J
a2|b2|c2|20190101|20181101|5|15|H|K
a2|b2|c2|20190101|20181101|6|16|I|L
```

Notice the incorrect month offset values in rows 4 thru 6

Comment: Good first Q! Good luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to kvantour answer (which is probably cleaner than mine because I would prefer use awk built-in functions rather than calling bash commands inside awk), here is your code fixed :

```
BEGIN{
    FS="|"
    OFS = FS
}
{
#   Date field is in column 4, offset is in column 5
#   Replace column 5 with the offset date

    cmd = "date -d '"$4" -"$5-1" months'  +'%Y%m%d'" # as suggested by @kvantour
    cmd | getline result
    close(cmd)
    $5 = result
    print $0
}
```

Result :

```
a1|b1|c1|20190101|20190101|1|11|A|D
a1|b1|c1|20190101|20181201|2|12|B|E
a1|b1|c1|20190101|20181101|3|13|C|F
a2|b2|c2|20190101|20190101|4|14|G|J
a2|b2|c2|20190101|20181201|5|15|H|K
a2|b2|c2|20190101|20181101|6|16|I|L
```

More [informations](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Close-Files-And-Pipes.html) here.

> Without the call to close(), awk creates child processes to run the commands, until it eventually runs out of file descriptors for more pipelines.

Comment: I would explicitly mention the reason for the `close`. Also, you could use `$5-1` instead of `- "$5" months + 1 months.

Comment: Thanks @kvantour, I quoted the reason of using `close` (instead of trying to explain it and be wrong :p)

Comment: It needs to be `$5 = ( (cmd | getline result) > 0 ? result : "N/A" ); close(cmd)` or similar to handle date/getline failures sensibly. See http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to call an external `date` utility or gawk-specific time functions for this, it's just math:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS="|" }
{
    delta = $5 - 1
    year  = substr($4,1,4)
    month = substr($4,5,2)
    day   = substr($4,7)
    month = month - delta
    if (month <= 0) {
        year--
        month += 12
    }
    $5 = sprintf("%04d%02d%02d",year,month,day)
    print
}
$
$ awk -f tst.awk file
a1|b1|c1|20190101|20190101|1|11|A|D
a1|b1|c1|20190101|20181201|2|12|B|E
a1|b1|c1|20190101|20181101|3|13|C|F
a2|b2|c2|20190101|20190101|4|14|G|J
a2|b2|c2|20190101|20181201|5|15|H|K
a2|b2|c2|20190101|20181101|6|16|I|L
```

Comment: Just for safety, it might be that `month` is bigger than 12 and at the same time, could  be multiple years off. `if (month > 0 ) { year+= int((month-1)/12); month = (month-1)%12+1}; if (month < 1) { year-=int(month/12)-1; month=month%12 + 12 }`

Comment: Yup that's possible. If the OP says it can happen I'll make the update. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Using GNU awk, any date-conversions should be performed with the date functions provided. The two useful time-functions for this problem are `mktime` and `strftime`:

> - **`mktime(datespec)`**: This converts a date specification string, `datespec`, of the form `YYYY MM DD hh mm ss` into a Unix epoch time, i.e. the total seconds since 1970 01 01 UTC. Since gawk-4.2.1 you can use the `utc-flag` to indicate `datespec` is in UTC or not.
> - **`strftime(format,timestamp)`**: This converts an epoch-time `timestamp` into a formatted string (same formatting as the `date` command). You can use the `utc-flag` the indicate that the returned time should be in UTC or in the local time-zone.
>
> More info in the [GNU awk manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Time-Functions)

The code becomes now: `convert.awk`

```
BEGIN {FS=OFS="|"}
{ d=$4
  time=mktime(substr(d,1,4)" "substr(d,5,2)+1-$5" "substr(d,7,2)" 00 00 00")
  $5=strftime("%Y%m%d",time)
  print
}' file
```

and you run this with:

```
$ awk -f convert.awk file.txt
```

`mktime` is remarkably *additive*. So the string you pass of the form `YYYY MM DD hh mm ss` does not need to be a correct date, you can have incorrect values. For example the string `2019 01 32 00 00 00` is equivalent to `2019 02 01 00 00 00` and `2019 5 -10 00 00 00` is equivalent to `2019 04 20 00 00 00` and even further `2019 -19 -10 00 00` is equivalent to `2017 04 20 00 00`

**Note:** since we modify the time directly in `mktime`, we do not need to worry about daylight saving time (see comment).

Comment: @EdMorton Aha indeed. This only seems to be dangerous when you change the time outside of `mktime` by subtracting seconds (`$ TZ='Europe/Monaco' awk 'BEGIN{t=mktime("2019 05 01 00 00 00"); print strftime("%FT%T",t); print strftime("%FT%T",t-86400*120)}`)